# How to change state store type of KTable from KeyValueStore to VersionedKeyValueStore in Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams binder?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a question about Kafka Streams.
If I consume KTable, it will automatically materialized as KeyValueStore. I want to change this to VersionedKeyValueStore.
Also, if I set `topology.optimization` to `all`, then changelog for that materialized store is not created but original consuming topic is used as a changelog topic.
How can I change type of materialized store from KeyValueStore to VersionedKeyValueStore?

```
fun process() = BiConsumer<KStream<String, String>, KTable<String, String>> { input, table ->
    input.join(table) { value1, value2 ->
        Pair(value1, value2)
    }.peek { key, value -> println("$key: $value") }
}
```

I have materialized KTable as VersionedKeyValueStore, but changelog topic has created although I've set `topology.optimization` to `all`.

```
fun process() = BiConsumer<KStream<String, String>, KTable<String, String>> { input, table ->
    val storedTable = table
        .toStream()
        .groupByKey()
        .aggregate(
            { byteArrayOf() },
            { _, value, _ -> value.toByteArray() },
            Materialized.`as`(store)
        )
    val store = Stores.persistentVersionedKeyValueStore("kafka-streams-test-store", Duration.ofDays(1))
    val stream = input.join(storedTable) { value1, value2 ->
        Pair(value1, value2)
    }.peek { key, value -> println("$key, ${value?.first}, ${value?.second?.decodeToString()") }
}
```

Comment: This maybe a gap that needs to be addressed from the binder. Binder currently only  allows you to create a `KeyValueStore`. Could you create an issue in the repository and provide more context and link to this thread? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues

Comment: This also provides some more information about the state store support in the Kafka Streams binder: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/kafka/kafka-streams-binder/state-store.html